# Install Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) on Windows 10 in 2021

Tags: active-directory

**Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC)** disappeared after Windows 20H2 update was installed.  I was looking for one for Windows 10 Enterprise Edition.  Navigate through Settings > Windows Feature Turn On or Off > Apps & Features > Optional Features > More Windows feature and select **Active Directory lightweight Directory Services**.  Unfortunately, it does not provide what I was looking for.

What happen to ADUC?  Is it no longer available to Windows Users?  This is 2021 and nothing works.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is more likely to get an answer on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RSAT tools are not carried (preserved) after the feature-update (upgrade) of Windows 10. These tools are different for different versions of Windows 10, due to version-specific dependency.

You may enable the Optional Feature either through the graphical interface or PowerShell (cmdlet listed below to check the status of various RSAT tools):

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, State
```